# Flutter Dio Post DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404]

Tags: sql, flutter, dio

I'm trying to add data to the sql database with dio via the web service running on the server. It works when I try it via Postman and via browser. But when I try on Flutter side, I get DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404].

My Model:

```
class SessionInfo{
int? sessionID;
String? sessionGroupID;
int? userID;
int? companyID;
int? depID;
String? IPAdress;
String? hostName;
DateTime? login;
DateTime? logout;

SessionInfo({
this.sessionID, this.sessionGroupID,
this.userID, this.companyID, this.depID,
this.IPAdress, this.hostName, this.login, this.logout
});

Map<String, dynamic> toJson(){
return {
  'ID': sessionID,
  'SESSIONGUID': sessionGroupID,
  'USERID': userID,
  'SIRKETID': companyID,
  'SUBEID': depID,
  'IPADRESS': IPAdress,
  'HOSTNAME': hostName,
  'GIRIS': login == null ? null : login?.toIso8601String(),
  'CIKIS': logout == null ? null : logout?.toIso8601String(),
};
}

SessionInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map):
    sessionID = map['ID'],
    sessionGroupID = map['SESSIONGUID'],
    userID = map['USERID'],
    companyID = map['SIRKETID'],
    depID = map['SUBEID'],
    IPAdress = map['IPADRESS'],
    hostName = map['HOSTNAME'],
    login = DateTime.parse(map['GIRIS']),
    logout = DateTime.parse(map['CIKIS']);

@override
String toString() {
return 'SessionInfo{sessionID: $sessionID, sessionGroupID: $sessionGroupID, userID: 
$userID, companyID: $companyID, depID: $depID, IPAdress: $IPAdress, hostName: 
$hostName, login: $login, logout: $logout}';
}
}
```

My Dio Codes:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
import 'package:onlinebekci/core/model/session_info.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:onlinebekci/core/model/user.dart';

enum _DioServicePaths { login, sessioninfo }

class DioService {
  Dio _dio = Dio();
  DioService() : _dio = Dio(BaseOptions(baseUrl: 'http://xx.xx.x.xx.:xx/'));

  Future<bool> sessionInfo(SessionInfo info) async {
    final response = await _dio.post(
   _DioServicePaths.sessioninfo.name,
   data: info.toJson(),
  );
  return response.statusCode == HttpStatus.created;
  }
  }
```

i can connect with dio get which i use for login process. So the connection is normally no problem. But when I try to post, I get 404 error.

Comment: Why are you calling `_dio.post` with `_DioServicePaths.sessioninfo.name` as its first parameter? The first parameter should be the path (as a string), the string you're passing is `"sessioninfo"`. You should save the path you want to use in a String variable, not in an enum.

Comment: My login function works like this and without any problems. '_DioServicePaths.login.name' However, as you said, I changed it as follows and the result did not change. 'final response = await _dio.post(
      'http://xx.xxx.xx.xx/xxxx/sessioninfo',
      data: info.toJson(),
    );'

Comment: It works if your path happens to be `"login"` or `"sessioninfo"`. Check if the path you are using is exactly the same (including http/https, the port number after the colon, the path part after the first slash...) you are using in Postman or the browser.

Comment: The path is true i check it.

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. My node file was mistake. The problem solved.

Comment: Oh, this happens all the time. Have a nice day.